# How to sync ngrx/store with the Angular 4 router

Tags: angular, router, ngrx-store

At the moment I have no routing but I do have a default state and a working set of reducers. A simplified version looks like this:

```
const defaultMapState: MapState = {
  baseLayer: 'roadmap',
  overlays: []
};
```

Then I have some actions that manipulate that state, e.g.:

- MAP_SET_BASELAYER
- MAP_ADD_OVERLAY
- MAP_REMOVE_OVERLAY

I'm trying to support the following scenarios:

1. Have 2 URL parameters, baselayer and overlays. On initialisation of the app use those values to set the state. If a value is missing, grab the value for that variable form the defaultState.
2. After each action, execute some sort of middleware to sync the route with the current state.
3. If the URL changes (without being triggered by an action) update the state.

I'm lost here. I have found '@ngrx/router-store' but I'm not sure how that works and if it's even intended to solve these problems.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?